# Debugging with AOSP

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-source

I am new to Android system source code. My issue is that while debugging using Android Studio, the control goes to the wrong location in the source file while I step into it, i.e., it goes elsewhere in the source file, not to the method it should have stepped into. I know this issue sounds really silly, but has anyone else encountered it?

Also do you have any recommendations on how I would go about learning how the control flows within the Android system? I could not find many blogs on this topic (nor many questions and answers on StackOverflow about this either), and the Android documentation is not really helpful. I did download and build AOSP, but not sure where to go from there. Any pointers would be helpful!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android open source project you can see this link https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

For Access online source you can see this link http://androidxref.com/ it is very good for explore ASOP.

I am Embedded android developer . you can ask me any question related to ASOP on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you! My question was more about debugging from an Android application, how do you step into the Android source code?

Comment: you can download source code sdk from sdk manager than you can explore only java classes of android source.

Comment: please you ask separate question not on comment.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging android framework libraries or native applications like surfaceflinger is tricky. The documentation on android site leaves lot of details to imagination.

Please start with [Debugging Android Framework applications](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html) link to understand how to organize your source code, eclipse setup etc. The other articles on that site go into debugging of native applications as well as native libs loaded by Java applications. I suggest start there to save yourself lot of time.